# placing text on carousel image bootstrap

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a carousel image. I have text to be displayed at a particular location on that image. carousel-caption is placing text always at center. when i change it to particular location by changing margins it is not getting responsive.

Answer (score 1):

By default `carousel caption` is coming at bottom side, not sure why this happening with you, but

[see this example](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#carousel)

If you want to show your text at any particular location than the **best way** is to use `position` not `margins`.

Also, you have to set that position in the `Percentage` instead of `Pixel`. So, it will be responsive.

USE `carousel-caption` class like following:

```
.carousel-caption {
    margin: 0px; 
    padding: 0px; 
    background: none;
    top: 20%;
    left: 30%;        
    position: absolute;
}
```